# possible solutions for deploying and keeping ubuntu computers up to date (and the same)

Tags: linux, configuration-management

I have access to a small linux pool of around 20 computers. I'd like to come up with a **simple** and **easy to configure** solution that allows me to

- deploy the same configuration to new computers
- distribute software installs to all computers
- keep all computers in sync when it comes to installed software & configurations

I'm aware of Ubuntu's Landscape, but this solution is too expensive for me.

Right now I'm deploying new installs by hand and I manage the computers with [cssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssh/) but this solution doesn't seem practical in the long run.

Deploying the same install onto new machines could probably be achieved by using `PXE` but how about the `keeping systems up to date and properly configured` part? Are there any easy to configure & use solutions out there? I'm aware of [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/) which seems too overblown to me, but maybe I'm wrong.

I'd be happy to hear from you about your solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just spend some time and learn [puppet master](https://puppetlabs.com/). After you get used to the main concepts it's a beauty to work and in the long run will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/discover.html).  You could use it as an orchestration tool, so you'd be able to run:

```
ansible webservers -m apt -a "name=apache2 state=latest"
```

Or something similar, having first defined "webservers"

```
[webservers]
www1.example.com
www2.example.com
```

Another option is [Salt](http://saltstack.org/), but I've used Salt in the past and found it to be quite unstable at times.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 20 computers then you can just setup authentication using `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` and when you need to make a change on all of them just use a script on your controlling computer, for example:

```
for hostname in hostname1 hostname2 hostname3 hostname4; do
  ssh "root@$hostname" apt-get install something
done
```

The problem is that all computers have to be running. You can use for example Wake on Lan to start them.

Comment: I'd say this is fine for 1-5 computers, after 5 it all gets a bit cray-zee.